# Command line string Variable comparison

Tags: command-line

I've been trying to compare my computername to some pre-set string. From reading around on google, namely http://commandwindows.com/batchfiles-branching.htm, I've attempted the following and many variants of the same line with `/I`, `"%ComputerName"`, `A513242` etc

```
IF (%ComputerName% == "A513242") (
  EXIT) ELSE (
    ECHO "else taken")
```

where "A513242" is the result of calling `ECHO %ComputerName%`
this seems to always take the "else taken" branch.

Any help as to why the (`EXIT`) case is not being taken/ what syntactical mistake I am making would be appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
if "%ComputerName%"=="A513242" (exit) else (echo "else taken")
```

Comment: Any explanation as to why OP's variant doesn't work?

Comment: @klaus triendl - Refer to the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47035821/batch-if-else-condition-for-start-function-executes-regardless